# TypeError: createElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, char, typeerror, vuejs3

HOW TO FIX THIS.
as I understand it, so far vue-chart.js doesn't work well with Vue 3, but it's still interesting how to do it.  This is not the first time I have already addressed this topic.

```
BaseChart.js?8ea9:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: createElement is not a function
at Proxy.render (BaseChart.js?8ea9:7)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:427)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4194)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4320)
at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4103)
at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4061)
at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3656)
at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3852)
at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3761)
```

Comment: It should be `document.createElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using current version of `vue-chart.js` (2.x) with Vue 3.

`vue-chart.js` 2.x is for Vue 2 ONLY and there is no version for [Vue 3 yet](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/699)

Either use Vue 2 or switch to different Vue wrapper for chart.js which has [support for Vue 3](https://github.com/victorgarciaesgi/vue-chart-3)